# If A + ~A = 1 why ~A*~B*~C*~D + A*B*C*D != 1?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In Boolean algebra the law says that $A$ or complement of $A$ is $1$, then why $ABCD$ or its complement $ABCD$ is not also $1$ ?

Comment: Because not ABCD is not (not A and not B and not C and not D)!

Comment: Look up the DeMorgan's theorem to understand what not ABCD actually is and why.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$X + \overline X = 1$$ and for $X=ABCD$, we have: $$(ABCD) + \overline{ABCD}=1$$

But, $$\overline{ABCD} \color{red}{\neq} \overline A \, \overline B \, \overline C \, \overline D$$ Take for example, $A= 0, B = 1, C=0, D= 1$: The LHS is $1$ and the RHS is $0$.